# sum a table's column by id and save in another table

Tags: php, laravel

There are three tables in my project : `storages`,  `storage_products` and `storage_managers`

Now, lets there are 2 storages (as shown in the image) in the storage table, in `storage_products` table, there are 6 rows as shown in the image :

[image]

table `storage_products`

[image]

table `storages`

[image]

table `storage_managers`

What I want is: each time the function is hit, it will sum up column `quantity` from table `storage_products` for respective storage_ids in such way that the table `storage_managers` will look like the following table after execution:

[image]

it will sum up the column `quantity` for all `storage_id` for all different `product_id` where `transfer_type` is 1. My codes from controller is:

```
foreach($storages as $storage => $val){
    $storage_id[] =  $storages[$storage]->id;
    $get_storage[] = Storage::with('storageProducts')->whereIn('id', $storage_id)->get();
    foreach($get_storage as $product => $val){
        foreach($val as $d){
                    
            foreach($d->storageProducts as $g){
                $a[$d->storageProducts[$g]->id] = StorageProduct::where('transfer_type',1)                                                
                                      ->where('product_id',$products[$product]>product_id)
                                      ->whereIn('storage_id',$storage_id)
                                      ->sum('quantity');

            }
                    
        }
   }
```

But It's actually not working.

Comment: 1. It is bad practice to store calculated data in the database, unless you have a valid reason. Refer here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/202758/bad-practice-to-store-calculated-data-in-database 2. What you want is `groupBy(storage_id, product_id)` and then `sum(quantity)` on `storage_products` table

Comment: Unless this is because you have a terrible performance problem, or because you need to store some sort of audit data (when the original data might be changed or deleted) then there should be no reason to store it anywhere - just run the query when you need to know the information.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, actually  I am getting no other way to store stocks for respective storage and products, thats why  ...

Comment: Yes but the point is, why do you need to _store_ those values? Why not just query them when you want to know them?